# Running long process in aspx vs windows service

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

Wondering if there is a performance difference between letting a long running process hang in asp.net vs running the process via a windows service.  I have done this once before and the windows service was much quicker and didnt bog down my system, whereas the asp.net request seemed to wreak havoc.  I have no idea why, but I need to explain it to some decision makers at my work.

Comment: Please define "long running".  In a web app, 2 minutes can be long running, if the user is waiting for a response.  The length of time this runs may play into the answer we come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre probably using up all the ASP.NET worker threads.  See this article for more info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx

Look for the section titled "Threading in ASP.NET"

That article also links [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164139.aspx) in case you miss it, for more info.